# How can i UI Automate different views in the storyboard using different UI TestFiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ui-automation

I am new to UI Automation in iOS using Xcode 7, i need to automate all the views in my storyboard, for each view i need to add different test files and test them separately however only the first screen gets automated and throws the error and fails for the second

The error is **UI Testing Failure**

Any help would be appreciated

P.S :  I am using xcode7-ui-testing and not instruments

My Scenario for example - 2 screens
1) Login
2) Home

I have two different UITest classes for the 2 views, when I run the tests, only the Login Test passes and it fails in the Home screen for UIAutomation.